# PGFplots: How to align the equations of the legendentries at the equal sign?

Tags: pgfplots, align, legend

How to align the legend equations at the equal sign knowing that this code shows the following error

> Missing } inserted. \end{axis}
>   ?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend cell align=left,
legend style={legend pos=north west}
]
  \addplot[domain=0:2] {x^2};
  \addplot[domain=0:4] {x};
  \legend{
    \begin{align*}
    $yy&=x^2$\\
    $y&=x$
    \end{align*}
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Edit

This code snippet

```
\legend{
$\begin{aligned}
yy&=x^2\\
y&=x
\end{aligned}$
}
```

results in

[image]

while this one

```
\legend{
$\begin{aligned}
yy&=x^2\\
y&=x\\ & \rule{0pt}{1ex}
\end{aligned}$
}
```

results in

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really clear to me exactly what you want. Is this it? (I added colours so it's possible to distinguish the lines.)

It appears that even with two lines in the `aligned`, the node in the legend matrix has the height of a single line. I don't know why this happens. The workaround below is to first use `\begin{aligned}[t]` which places the first line of the `aligned` on the baseline. This makes the first line in the `aligned` align with the first plot in the legend.\

The next key thing to do is to add more legend entries, one for each additional plot. You don't want more text in the legend, but you want something that makes the nodes as high as they would be if there were text there. So add a `\strut`, this is a zero width box with some height (and depth).

Hence, if you have two plots, then use `\legend{$\begin{aligned}[t]...\end{aligned}$, \strut }`. If you have three plots, use `\legend{$\begin{aligned}[t]...\end{aligned}$, \strut, \strut}`. And so on.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend cell align=left,
legend style={legend pos=north west}
]
  % added colours to plots
  \addplot[blue,domain=0:2] {x^2};
  \addplot[red,domain=0:4] {x};
  \legend{
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
    yy&=x^2\\[-2pt]
    y&=x
    \end{aligned}$,
    \strut % second legend entry
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## A different approach

A different way altogether could be to do the alignment manually. Here I defined a macro `\LHS` (left hand side) with an optional and a mandatory argument. You use the optional argument to set the width of the LHS of the equations (default 1.5em), and the mandatory one holds the text/symbols that is the LHS. It makes a box of a fixed width, which makes the `=` aligned, and is used like this: `\legend{$\LHS{yy}=x^2$,$\LHS{y}=x$}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\LHS}[2][1.5em]{\hspace{#1}\mathllap{#2}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend cell align=left,
legend style={legend pos=north west}
]
  % added colours to plots
  \addplot[blue,domain=0:2] {x^2};
  \addplot[red,domain=0:4] {x};
  \legend{
    $\LHS{yy}=x^2$,
    $\LHS{y}=x$
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Fine trick, this \strut! Is this documented somewhere in the manual?

Comment: @Bernard `\strut`s are mentioned, in this case it's just an easy way of getting an empty legend entry with a full height node.

Comment: I must I don't understand the way TikZ  takes into account the environment height. It's so much simpler and direct to do with pstricks.

Comment: @Bernard In this case I don't really know what happens either, normally the node in which the legend entry is placed would encompass the entire `aligned` regardless of `[t]`, so you wouldn't have to do anything special. I don't know (and haven't at this point tried to find out) what `pgfplots` does exactly that changes it.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. IMO, I think the first approach is more appealing in case different vertical alignments are needed. It doesn't really matter, but the entries images are not identical to each other in terms of the vertical alignment with their respective text, so I hope something like this would be fixed in the future. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I found something strange when trying to add a third plot. This [code](https://pastebin.com/tasunyCR) results in [this legend](https://ibb.co/fezK98). So, how can I make the legend robust to the entries numbers without fixing it manually?

Comment: @Diaa You need another legend entry, currently there are only two. Add `,\strut` after the `\strut` that is currently there.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Many thanks, it works. However, if you come up with more robust solution to make the text automatically aligns with its image, it would be great to share it here since for multiple plots, the spacing of entries have to be manually adjusted as I did [here](https://pastebin.com/JQMbu6mE) in order to get [this ouput](https://ibb.co/gNUfXT).

Comment: @Diaa The second option described above does that. I don't have any better ideas.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am so grateful for your patience, but if you don't mind, could you give me some ideas for aligning both the equal signs and the text words for this [MWE](https://pastebin.com/nZzJmiEY)?

Comment: @Diaa https://gist.github.com/TorbjornT/582ba77168ee6c31011fc6c9a6a5b9c6

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Many thanks! I can't be more grateful.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
\legend{
\begin{align*}
$yy&=x^2$\\
$y&=x$
\end{align*}
}
```

with

```
\legend{
$\begin{aligned}
yy&=x^2\\
y&=x
\end{aligned}$
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the output is [this](https://ibb.co/iHwyj8), which makes the second line improperly placed.

Comment: Perhaps you can control the TikZ box height?

Comment: You can fool it adding a third aligned line: ` \\
     & \rule{0pt}{1ex}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the images don't align accordingly as shown [here](https://ibb.co/edzRNT).

Comment: @Diaa How should the plot line in the legend line up with the equation? Do you want `\begin{aligned}[t] ...`

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I've already tried that. Unfortunately it has  the result of a frame with a shorter height.

Comment: @Bernard I noticed (hence the `\strut` in my answer), I was mainly trying to find out what exactly the desired output was.