# PGFplots-legend: Left-align text entry with its first respective entry below

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, legend

Following-up [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440045/2288), I would like to left-align both text entries with their first ones below them, respectively. In other words, I need to move `text` to be left-aligned with `yy=x^2` and `another text` to be left-aligned with `zzyyz=x^3`

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc}
\newcommand{\LHS}[2][1.5em]{\hspace{#1}\mathllap{#2}}
\newcommand{\RHS}[2][1.5em]{\mathrlap{#2}\hspace{#1}} 


\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    legend cell align=left,
    legend columns=2,
    legend style={
        anchor=south,
        at={([yshift=2mm]current axis.north)},%,above=0cm,left=0mm,
        cells={align=center},
        /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=5mm}
}
    ]
    \addplot[red] {x};
    \addplot[blue,domain=0:2] {x^2};
    \addplot[orange] {-x};
    \addplot[green] {x^3};
    \addplot[green] {x^3};
    \addplot[green] {x^3};
    \legend{
        text,
        another text,
        $\LHS{yy}=x^2$,
        $\LHS[3em]{zzyyz}=\RHS{x^3}$ reference,
        $\LHS{k}=xyz$,
        $\LHS[3em]{kk}=\RHS{xz}$ cite,
    }
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just add `\hspace{0.5em}` before `text` and `another text`.

Comment: @marmot Actually, I will have to manually adjust this spacing every single time I have a different equation left-hand-side, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Well, you sort of went this way when aligning the equality signs. In my answer below I show how to compute the distances. This also reveals that the distances between the red line and yy on the one hand and between the green line and zzyyz do not exactly coincide. You could make them coincide, of course, by choosing as first argument of `\LHS` some desired distance plus the width of yy or zzyyz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are, in a way, manually adjusting the equations in order to get the equality sign aligned. You could then ask Ti*k*Z (or the calc package, *not* library) to compute the required horizontal space for you.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc}
\newcommand{\LHS}[2][1.5em]{\hspace{#1}\mathllap{#2}}
\newcommand{\RHS}[2][1.5em]{\mathrlap{#2}\hspace{#1}} 


\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    legend cell align=left,
    legend columns=2,
    legend style={
        anchor=south,
        at={([yshift=2mm]current axis.north)},%,above=0cm,left=0mm,
        cells={align=center},
        /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=5mm}
}
    ]
    \addplot[red] {x};
    \addplot[blue,domain=0:2] {x^2};
    \addplot[orange] {-x};
    \addplot[green] {x^3};
    \addplot[green] {x^3};
    \addplot[green] {x^3};
    \legend{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myw}{1.5em-width("$yy$")}%
        \hspace{\myw pt}text,\pgfmathsetmacro{\myw}{3em-width("$zzyyz$")}%
        \hspace{\myw pt}another text,
        $\LHS{yy}=x^2$,
        $\LHS[3em]{zzyyz}=\RHS{x^3}$ reference,
        $\LHS{k}=xyz$,
        $\LHS[3em]{kk}=\RHS{xz}$ cite,
    }
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A perhaps more appealing output is achieved by fixing the indent, `\myindent` in the following MWE, and than shift the stuff accordingly. This might be the better choice even if you do not add text because then the indent will be universal.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc}
\newcommand{\LHS}[2][1.5em]{\hspace{#1}\mathllap{#2}}
\newcommand{\RHS}[2][1.5em]{\mathrlap{#2}\hspace{#1}} 
\newlength\myindent
\myindent=0.5em

\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    legend cell align=left,
    legend columns=2,
    legend style={
        anchor=south,
        at={([yshift=2mm]current axis.north)},%,above=0cm,left=0mm,
        cells={align=center},
        /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=5mm}
}
    ]
    \addplot[red] {x};
    \addplot[blue,domain=0:2] {x^2};
    \addplot[orange] {-x};
    \addplot[green] {x^3};
    \addplot[green] {x^3};
    \addplot[green] {x^3};
    \legend{\hspace{\myindent}text,
        \hspace{\myindent}another text,\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywleft}{\myindent+width("$yy$")}%
        $\LHS[\mywleft pt]{yy}=x^2$,\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywright}{\myindent+width("$zzyyz$")}%
        $\LHS[\mywright pt]{zzyyz}=\RHS{x^3}$ reference,\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywleft}{\myindent+width("$yy$")}%
        $\LHS[\mywleft pt]{k}=xyz$,\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywright}{\myindent+width("$zzyyz$")}%
        $\LHS[\mywright pt]{kk}=\RHS{xz}$ cite,
    }
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer! you even answered my question I was writing :)