# How to align negative and positive values inside an align environment?

Tags: equations, align, split

I have the following equation inside an `align` and `split` environment but I would like to align the values of the constants below (of `c_1`, `c_2` and `c_3`) even with the negative sign.

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split} 
    \cos(x) &= c_1 + c_2x^2 + c_3x^4 \\
            &= c_1 + x^2(c_2 + c_3x^2) \\
    \text{where} \\
    c_1 &= 0.99940307 \\
    c_2 &= -0.49558072 \\
    c_3 &= 0.03679168 
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

This code generates this:

[image]

I wanted to align all values after the minus sign, like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps `c_1 &= \hphantom{-}0.99940307`?

Comment: Note, however, that you are misusing both the `align` and the `split` environments, and that `\text{where}` should probably be `\intertext{where}`.  I advise you to have a look at the manual of the `amsmath` package: on a TeXLive installation, it can be brought up by typing `texdoc amsmath` at a shell prompt.

Comment: You could create break your column in two so that you can align on the decimal point.

Comment: @GuM: `\shortintertext{where}` might be better with the `mathtools` package.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I actually *knew* that, but I didn’t want to intimidate a (presumed) beginner with such niceties… ;-)

Comment: @GuM: :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Aligning the minus sign in a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/311018/5764)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to use a phantom where a sign is missing; `\mathbin{\phantom{-}}` will behave exactly like `-` in all situations, as far as spacing is concerned, but printing nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% first strategy
\newcommand{\nm}{\mathbin{\phantom{-}}}

% second strategy
\begingroup\lccode`~=``\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathbin{\phantom{-}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode``="8000 }

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
    \cos(x) &= c_1 + c_2x^2 + c_3x^4 \\
            &= c_1 + x^2(c_2 + c_3x^2) \\
    \text{where} \\
    c_1 &= \nm 0.99940307 \\
    c_2 &=   - 0.49558072 \\
    c_3 &= \nm 0.03679168 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
    \cos(x) &= c_1 + c_2x^2 + c_3x^4 \\
            &= c_1 + x^2(c_2 + c_3x^2) \\
    \text{where} \\
    c_1 &= `0.99940307 \\
    c_2 &= -0.49558072 \\
    c_3 &= `0.03679168 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The first strategy is simpler from a programming point of view; for the second I used a character that's not commonly used in math and made it “math active” expanding to the same phantom as in `\nm`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following the approach provided in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/441715/2288)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newlength{\myindent}
\setlength{\myindent}{10pt}
\newcommand{\LHS}[2][\myindent]{\hspace{#1}\mathrlap{#2}} 
\newcommand{\RHS}[2][\myindent]{\mathrlap{#2}\hspace{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \begin{split} 
            \cos(x) &= c_1 + c_2x^2 + c_3x^4 \\
            &= c_1 + x^2(c_2 + c_3x^2) \\
            \shortintertext{where}
            c_1 &= \LHS{0.99940307}\\
            c_2 &=\RHS{-}0.49558072\\
            c_3 &= \LHS{0.03679168}
        \end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The spacing is, however, off. The `-` on the r.h.s. is a unary operator. Add a line `c_2 &= -0.49...` to see what I mean.

Comment: @campa I am sorry I couldn't understand what you mean. If you are talking about the spacing between `-` and `0.49...`, it can be controlled by setting the length `\myindent`.